# How to mount image using mount(2)

Tags: c, linux, macos

I cannot mount some IMAGE on the MacOSX 10.10 via C function [mount()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mount.2.html).

I use following code

```
...
    char ImgPath[m_IMGName.size() + 1];
    memcpy(ImgPath, m_IMGName.c_str(), m_IMGName.size() + 1);
    struct hfs_mount_args data;
    data.fspec = ImgPath;
    if(mount("hfs+", m_TargetPath.c_str(), MNT_RDONLY, &data)){
        throw SysCallTestExeption(errno, "mount() is failed!", GET_FILE_LINE_FUNC_ARG);
    }
...
```

And when I start the program I get the error "mount() is failed! Error(Operation not supported by device)."

And image was mounted if I use the following command:

```
sudo hdiutil attach -mountpoint "${MountPointPath}" "${Image}"
```

Also, when I use [mount()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount) on the Linux - All is OK.
Following Linux code:

```
...
if(mount(m_IMGName.c_str(), m_TargetPath.c_str(), m_FSType.c_str(), 0, m_Opts.c_str())){
        throw SysCallTestExeption(errno, "mount() is failed!", GET_FILE_LINE_FUNC_ARG);
    }
...
```

Comment: Hi, I'm dealing with the exact same issue. perhaps did you find any other image format besides `dmg` which can be used in `mount(2)` command to mount the image file directly to mountpoint ? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not programmed OSX for several years, so I can't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `hfs+` type in

```
mount("hfs+", m_TargetPath.c_str(), MNT_RDONLY, &data)
```

You should use `hfs` to handle both HFS and HFS+. Look for example at [mount_hfs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_hfs.8.html) command [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/diskdev_cmds/diskdev_cmds-491/mount_hfs.tproj/mount_hfs.c):

```
#define HFS_MOUNT_TYPE              "hfs"
```

Comment: Thanks! I made the similar code as [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/diskdev_cmds/diskdev_cmds-491/mount_hfs.tproj/mount_hfs.c) which you gave me. But it doesn't work :(
Also, I cannot mount the dmg image using mount_hfs/mount command from the shell/bash/terminal.
But I can mount image using command: 
sudo hdiutil attach -mountpoint "${MountPointPath}" "${Image}"

How can I mount dmg image using mount/mount_hfs commands or  using C language?
Thanks.

Comment: @Vadim If you are trying to mount apple `dmg` image, AFAIK this is a proprietary format, not well documented. See http://newosxbook.com/DMG.html. You may try to ask new question how to mount OS X proprietary `dmg` image programatically.

Comment: perhaps you're familiar with a different image format rather then `dmg` which can work in macOS. i also wish to mount my image file which is properly formatted to `hfs+`, and cannot perform the attaching of `dmg` image to device file programmatically.